# Training a model from already cropped images & their originals with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a 1000 images containing humans - both in their original version with surroundings and a manually cropped version around all of the human being with a little bit of padding.

So I'd like to create some kind of model that learns this cropping pattern to automatically crop other images accordingly.

Unfortunately my machine learning knowledge does not go beyond having done the usual which_number/dog_or_not classifier tutorials.

When I researched how to train a detection model based on my croppings, I only found the information that most/all(?) libraries use bounding boxes to mark the region of interest within the original image.

So is there a way to use the manually cropped images to calculate the bounding box coordinates within their original images or a library that can work with what I already have?

The gamma, brightness, contrast & saturation settings of the cropped images are often different than those of their originals.
Most cropped images have a file name that contains the original file name.

Thank you for your help!